# How to close a "Server-Sent Events"-connection on the server?

Tags: server-sent-events

Regarding this specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/

How does one close the opened connection on the server? Client-side wise it is easy, just call `close()`, but what should I do on the server? Just kill it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node.js:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    //...

    // client closes connection
    res.socket.on('close', function () {
      res.end();
      //...
    });

});
```

see example for implementation of SSE server in node.js:

https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/blob/master/nodechat/server.js

Comment: This is an old answer and the link is not active, but the solution worked for me (node 7, express 4) thanks!

Comment: Calling `res.end()` when using an event handling package may not be safe. See my separate answer for details.

Answer (score 13):

So, I've searched around for a solution built into the protocol, and it there does not appear to be one. If your server calls `response.emit('close')` or `response.end()`, the client will treat this like an error and attempt to reconnect to the server. (At least in the case of Chrome, it will attempt to reconnect indefinitely, unless it considers the network error fatal).

So it appears that one way or another, your client has to close the connection. That leaves two options. The first, is to simply assume any error from the server should close the EventSource.

```js
const sse = new EventSource('/events')
sse.onmessage = m => console.log(m.data)
sse.onerror = () => sse.close()
```

The above leaves a few things to be desired though. We are assuming that a network error is a graceful shutdown, this may not be the case. There may also be some scenarios where we *do* want the reconnect behavior.

So instead, why don't we just ask the client to gracefully shutdown itself! We have a way to send messages to the client from the server, so all we need to do is send a message from the server that says "shut me down".

```js
// client.js
const maxReconnectTries = 3

let reconnectAttempts = 0
const sse = new EventSource('/events')
sse.onmessage = m => {
  const { type, data } = JSON.parse(m.data)
  if (type === 'close') sse.close()
  else console.log(data)
}
sse.onerror = () => {
  if (reconnectAttempts > maxReconnectTries) {
    sse.close()
    alert("We have a baaad network error!")
  } else {
    reconnectAttempts++
  }
}
```

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express')


function sendEvent(res, type, data) {
  res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify({ type, data })}\n\n`)
}

function sseHandler(req, res) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  }

  let manualShutdown
  request.on('close', () => {
    console.log('disconnected.')
    clearTimeout(manualShutdown)  // prevent shutting down the connection twice
  })
  
  sendEvent(res, 'message', `Ping sent at ${new Date()}`)

  // when it comes time to shutdown the event stream (for one reason or another)
  setTimeout(() => {
    sendEvent(res, 'close', null)
    // give it a safe buffer of time before we shut it down manually
    manualShutdown = setTimeout(() => res.end(), clientShutdownTimeout)
  }, 10000)
}

const clientShutdownTimeout = 2000
const app = express()
app.get('/events', sseHandler)
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('server started on 4000'))
```

This covers all the areas that we need for a safe client/server implementation. If there's an issue on the server, we attempt to reconnect but can still notify the client if there's a failure. When the server wants the connection closed, it asks the client to close the connection. After two seconds, if the client has not shut down the connection we can assume something went wrong and close the connection server side.

What we are doing here is building a *protocol* on top of server sent events. It has a very simple api: `{ "type": "close" }` tells the client to close the server, and `{ "type": "message", "data": {"some": "data" }` tells the client this is a regular message.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just close the connection (kill it). I have not seen any talk about graceful disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the content-type the server sents other than "text/event-stream". 
This will close the clients eventsource.

Answer (score 1):

**Caution**: If you use a package to manage server-sent events in node.js, making a direct call to `response.end()` may cause the package to send additional data after `response.end()`, and this will crash the server with a "*WRITE after close*" error.

Instead of directly calling `response.end()`, my workaround was to call `response.emit('close')`, which allowed the package to handle the close.

Node.js documentation on **http.ServerResponse > Event.close**:

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_1

Comment: Which package are you using? I am running into this same issue.

Comment: I'm using sse-nodejs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse-nodejs).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up not using any package. The API provided is pretty simple to use. My question got answered here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797523/node-js-server-sent-events-route-continues-to-run-after-res-end-resulting-in/59798626?noredirect=1#comment105739184_59798626

Answer (score 1):

res.end() is not the way to go if the connection is being closed from the client side and might result in a ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END error later. If this the case, you are better off just undoing the logic that you added in the route.

An example can be found [Node.JS Server Sent Events: Route continues to run after res.end() resulting in ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797523/node-js-server-sent-events-route-continues-to-run-after-res-end-resulting-in?noredirect=1#comment105798817_59797523[here][1]).