# How to redirect when server-sent-event is finished in Flask on server side?

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events

### Question

How can one redirect to another page when server-sent-event is finished in Flask and on server side?

#### Problem description

An EventSource was implemented on client side code (JavaScript) and a Response was returned on server side code (Flask, Python). The EventSource will be closed if the last item from server was sent. I can't see a clear solution to redirect to another site via server side code. Maybe the answer is simple, but I'm not getting it.

#### Similar problem

A similar question is [How to stop Server-Sent Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645664/how-to-stop-server-sent-events) and one possible answer in the comment [How do server-sent events actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636165/how-do-server-sent-events-actually-work/11998868#11998868). I'm not sure, if it's the same for php and python, so I've started a new question for that. I also didn't get it.

**EDIT** [How do I close a Server-Send Events connection in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597367/how-do-i-close-a-server-send-events-connection-in-flask) is strongly related to this question. The question there is mainly to see how you can stop SSE from Flask.

### Working solution on client side

So I came up with a solution that worked (a progress bar), but only on the client side. How do I have to change the code to get a working example of reconnecting via Flask functions?

#### Relevant code snippets

HTML/Jinja

```
{% block additional_stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='data_import.css') }}" />
{%  endblock %}
{% block additional_javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/data_import.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"
             role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0"
             aria-valuemax="100">
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var source = new EventSource("/progress");

        source.addEventListener('import-progress', function(event)
            {
                $('.progress-bar')
                    .css('width', event.data + '%')
                    .attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);
            }, false
        );

        source.addEventListener('last-item', function()
            {
                source.close();
                redirect();
            }, false
        );
    }
);

# This works! But how to do the same thing without calling redirect()
# on client site?
function redirect()
{
    window.document.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" +
            window.location.host + "/products.html";
}
```

Flask

```
from foo import app
from flask import render_template, Response

@app.route('/data_import.html')
def data_import():
    return render_template(
        'data_import.html')


@app.route('/progress')
def progress():
    return Response(import_progress(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

def import_progress():
    """
    Just a small example
    """
    for number in range(1, 101):
        sse_id = str(number)
        sse_progress = str(number)
        sse_event = 'import-progress'

        if number == 100:
            sse_event = 'last-item'

        yield "id:{_id}\nevent:{event}\ndata:{progress}\n\n".format(
            _id=sse_id, event=sse_event, progress=sse_progress)
```

I tried a lot to get a redirect working. But I don't know exactly how to do it. Every attempt so far has failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is send the redirect URL as the last event - you'll still need to redirect using JavaScript, but you won't have to hard-code the path any more:

```
def import_progress():
    """
    Just a small example
    """
    for number in range(1, 101):
        sse_id = str(number)
        sse_data = str(number)
        sse_event = 'import-progress'

        if number == 100:
            sse_event = 'last-item'
            sse_data = url_for('product_list')

        yield "id:{_id}\nevent:{event}\ndata:{data}\n\n".format(
            _id=sse_id, event=sse_event, data=sse_data)
```

Then your last-item handler becomes:

```
source.addEventListener('last-item', function(event) {
     source.close();
     redirect(event.data);
   }, false
);
```

And `redirect` becomes a simple:

```
function redirect(url) {
  document.location = url;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's a nice solution without hardcoding the url in the JavaScript file. Thx to that! I still would prefer a solution without calling `redirecting()` in JavaScript file and do that with Flask's `redirect(url_for('foo'))` method. Or is this simply not possible? I can't upvote your answer yet, unfortunately - I will do it soon as I can.

Comment: Redirecting from the server side is simply not possible because you've already made the connection once you're consuming a SSE (just like you can't redirect a page once you've started sending it to the user without doing something on the client side).

Comment: As per the upvote - if it works for you, just hit the green check mark.  That will help others know that you found the answer helpful.  And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: _"Redirecting from the server side is simply not possible"_ is an important information. Thx! @SeanVieira