# How to identify server side SSE connection close from frontend Eventsource

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events, eventsource

I'm trying to popup  a message when the sse connection of the EventSource get closed from backend. I tried with `eventsource.onerror` and checked for state `CLOSED` of `EventSource.readyState` as well. But non of them get triggered.

Is there any way to identify the sse connection get closed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close a "Server-Sent Events"-connection on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534572/how-to-close-a-server-sent-events-connection-on-the-server)

Comment: @andykais it's valid solution for nodejs. I was using C backend and couldn't find a proper way to achieve this. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: No prob. By the way you can definitely implement something similar in C if you wanted. The only special part about what I suggested was setting up a protocol on top of SSE. You can do that in any language. Totally fine to leave your question open here, maybe someone has a C specific solution. If you find something that works yourself you can post that too!